# Regex to find everything in between

Tags: regex

I have the following regex which works when there is no leading /d,"There is  1 interface on the system:

or a trailing ",2017-01-...

Here is the regex:

```
(?m)(?<_KEY_1>\w+[^:]+?):\s(?<_VAL_1>[^\r\n]+)$
```

Here is a sample of what I am trying to parse:

```
1,"There is 1 interface on the system:
    Name               : Mobile Broadband Connection
    Description        : Qualcomm Gobi 2000 HS-USB Mobile Broadband Device 250F
    GUID               : {1234567-12CD-1BC1-A012-C1A1234CBE12}
    Physical Address   : 00:a0:c6:00:00:00
    State              : Connected
    Device type        : Mobile Broadband device is embedded in the system
    Cellular class     : CDMA
    Device Id          : A1000001234f67
    Manufacturer       : Qualcomm Incorporated
    Model              : Qualcomm Gobi 2000
    Firmware Version   : 09010091
    Provider Name      : Verizon Wireless
    Roaming            : Not roaming
    Signal             : 67%",2017-01-20T16:00:07.000-0700
```

I am trying to extract field names where for example Cellular class would equal CDMA but for all fields beginning after:

```
1,"There is 1 interface on the system:  (where 1 increments 1,2 3,4 and so on
```

and before the tailing ",2017-01....

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask why your string is that long? Can't each individual piece of information be it's own string?

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/qmuNpg/2. Something like that?

Comment: Or rather https://regex101.com/r/qmuNpg/3

Comment: Your string looks like a csv record, did you try to use a csv parser and to extract the second field before using your pattern? Then you only need to skip the first line. (*There is 1 interface on the system:*)

Answer (score 1):

You could use look-ahead to ensure that the strings you match come before a `",\d` sequence, and do not include a `"`. The latter would ensure you will only match between double quotes, of which the second has the pattern `",\d`:

```
/^\h*(?<_KEY_1>[\w\h]+?)\h*:\h*(?<_VAL_1>[^\r\n"]+)(?="|$)(?=[^"]*",\d)/gm
```

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hBhDOT/1)

NB: I put the `g` and `m` modifiers at the end, but if your environment requires them at the start with `(?m)` notation, that will work too of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your example string seems to be a record from a csv file. This is how I will accomplish the task with Python (2.7 or 3.x):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    results = []

    for fields in reader:
        lines = fields[1].splitlines()
        keyvals = [list(map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))) for line in lines[1:]]
        results.append(keyvals)

    print(results)
```

It can be done in a similar way with other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't responded to my comments or any of the answers,  but here is my answer - try

```
^\s*(?<_KEY_1>[\w\s]+?)\s*:\s*(?<_VAL_1>[^\r\n"]+).*$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qmuNpg/3).